# Inserting multiple SQL statements in codeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have the following SQL that works directly in MySQL

```
 INSERT INTO `my_tabel` (`data`) VALUES ("my_value");
 SELECT * from `my_tabel` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1
```

It inserts a row, and then gets the new row so that I can return the new ID to use later.

When I try to run the SQL in [codeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/) I get an error message stating that I have an error in my SQL

```
$m = new my_model();
$sql = 'INSERT INTO `my_tabel` (`data`) VALUES ("'.$my_value.'"); SELECT * from `my_tabel` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1';
$m->query($sql);
```

Running a single SQL statement works fine in [codeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/), but not when I add the second SELECT... statement.

Any ideas (or alternative solutions)?

Thanks

Comment: Don't put values in queries like that, it's very unsafe.

Do something like this:

    ```$m->query('INSERT INTO `my_tabel` (`data`) VALUES (?); SELECT * from `my_tabel` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1', array($my_value));```.

More info at the bottom of this page: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html

Comment: in php I'm adding `mysql_real_escape_string($value)`, I didn't add it to the question to keep the code simpler. I can see your solution adds security, so I will add that too

Comment: Thing is, if you use the question marks, you don't need to use `mysql_real_escape_string` anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyone's help. The solution that worked for me was

```
$m = my_model();
$m->data = $value;
$m->save();
echo $m->id;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not a limitation of CI but that of the database client libraries.

only a single query can be executed at a time.

Comment: +1 
PHP only allows a query to run 1 command at a time, in a single string.

If one wants to run multiple queries, you'll need to use the multi_query method. But since you're using CI, thats not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Why not run two `$m->query()` statements?  That way you can check the success of each individually from CI.

In most SQL interfaces, having multiple statements in a query is problematic because of the different types of result from each.  Even when calling a stored procedure, it is necessary to carefully craft the stored procedure not to return extraneous results, though even that can usually be handled with a special, relaxed api which allows multiple results.

Comment: Originally that was how I set it up, but I get the same error message. Running them both in separate functions works, but not when they are called at the same time.

Comment: @Eruant:  Huh?  How can you call separate functions at the same time?

Comment: Sorry to confuse. If I run the insert command on it's own it works. If I then edit the function to only run the select command, that works too. The problem happens when a write them both into the same function.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running 2 queries, to get the id created after the insert query use:

```
$this->db->insert_id();
```

Answer (score 0):

insert_id() is your friend!

```
$this->db->insert_id()
```

From here http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/helpers.html

So something like:

```
$insert_data = array(
  'data' => $my_value
);

$this->db->insert('my_table', $insert_data);

$last_id = $this->db->insert_id();
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the other answers, use  `$this->db->insert_id()` is better because there is a chance that another user inserts a row between your two queries. Since PHP can only execute one query at a time, this can become a race condition.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html#caching
You can use Caching to control multiple queries without conflicts.